# Property 'User' does not exist on type 'typeof db' sequelize in express typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with express typescript.

I was use sequelize-cli to generate User model. When I tried to get User from model.

I get an error: `Property 'User' does not exist on type 'typeof db'`

How can I access to User model inside my database model.

Thank you for your help.

This is my code.

**model/index.js**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.database,
    config.username,
    config.password,
    config
  );
}

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter((file) => {
    return (
      file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== basename && file.slice(-3) === '.js'
    );
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(
      sequelize,
      Sequelize.DataTypes
    );
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**model/user.js**

```
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      email: DataTypes.STRING,
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User',
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

**repository/auth.ts**

```
import DB from '../../database/models';

const { User } = DB; // Property 'User' does not exist on type 'typeof db'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `any` to fix this error:

```js
import db from '../../database/models';

const DB: any = db;
const { User } = DB;
```

Comment: Thank you for that!

One more question. If I don't want to using any type. Do you know how to implement the type for DB?

Comment: How we can add type for the DB constant. I am using the same code in the Typescript. I would like to add the type for that?. Can you suggest some solution for this

Answer (score 0):

On file `model/index.js`

You can change `module.exports = db;` to `export default db;`

Then you can import like this:

```
import db from '../../database/models';

const { User } = db;
```